# Allowing external users to receive Change notifications for calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have this setup:

Accessing my Organization with Client Credentials Flow, and enabled Calendars.ReadWrite to read "Read calendars in all mailboxes".

Created an Webhook for resource to subscribe for created,updated,deleted:

```
return [
        'changeType' => 'created,updated,deleted',
        'notificationUrl' => 'url',
        'resource' => '/users/'.$this->email.'/calendars/'.$this->calendarId.'/events',
        'expirationDateTime' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(4230)->toIso8601String(),
        'clientState' => 'Secret',
    ];
```

This works fine if the calendar i'am subscribing to is created and owned by my user.

But I want to subscribe to the shared calendars with me, lets say an **resource or shared calendar from another organization**.

When i subscribe to others, I can create the subscriptions successfully, but there is no events coming to my notificationUrl.

Is this not supported? The permission on my shared calendars is "Can see all details".

Thank you.